# Can't use my iMac's built-in webcam in Windows Image Acquisition(WIA)

Tags: c#, windows-8, webcam, visual-studio-2012, wia

I'm trying to use the built-in webcam from my iMac to use with Windows Image Acquisition (WIA), I'm trying to capture an image from my webcam, but when I tried to get the devices connected to my computer an exception got thrown `Exception from HRESULT: 0x80210015`. I'm using Windows 8, Visual Studio 2012 and I'm making the program in C#. Is it my webcam? Should I buy another webcam?

Comment: This is `WIA_S_NO_DEVICE_AVAILABLE` "No WIA hardware devices match the specifications given in the lDeviceType parameter." Looks like a driver/compatibility issue.

Comment: it seems that was the problem, in the end I had to take another approach, thanks

Comment: @Uriel: I have the same issue... what approach did you take exactly?

Comment: I had to get a compatible camera, I got a Microsoft webcam.